# Would a native speaker consider this dialogue natural?

Tags: grammar, style

I am practicing for the speaking part of TOEFL. Below is a practice speech for a sample question I made. I was wondering if it sounds natural to a native English speaker. I hope you could help me. Here it goes:

"Question: Do you think being a lawyer is still a good career choice, financially speaking?

No.......Most people think that becoming a lawyer is a sure way to get rich, but I don’t. Honestly, if there’s one thing my country doesn’t need more of, it’s lawyers. The market for lawyers is extremely competitive nowadays, at least in my country. Passing the bar exam isn’t enough to land you a job in a prestigious law firm. Highly sought-after lawyers came from top-tier law schools, graduated with Latin honors, and have a lot of friends in high places. If you don't have those things, don't expect a huge paycheck."

Comment: I would change the tense of the first two verbs in the second to last sentence - "come from" and "graduate with", specifically.  The entire rest of the paragraph is in present tense, and it sounds better if this line is as well.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Rod. If you simply provide text and ask us to check it, we regard it as proof-reading, and we don't do that. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for guidelines for valid questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

That is not only natural sounding dialogue, it's well-written and grammatically meticulous.

The only note I would make is that in casual speech, at least in North American English, one would usually say simply "honors" rather than "Latin honors."

> graduated with honors...